# Can an SSL cert/key pair indicate that they need an intermediate

Tags: tls

I generate a cert and key. When I enter them into a hosting provider their form fails validation saying that the intermediate is invalid. I didn't enter an intermediate, so I so I filed a support issue. They counter that my cert/key pair has an issues because they can use a self signed pair on a test environment. Can a cert/key pair indicate that they require an intermediate?

Comment: Can you post screenshots? And the text of the certificate?

Comment: Yes, need a bit more info to find where the issue is. A trusted cert will require an intermediate but if I understand what you're saying here, a local certificate on your own server you shouldn't need one, however you'll be required by your browser to agree to the security exception to access it. Hence it may be a prob with the cert/key pair.

Comment: Wait, I just reread this. Are you saying that you are generating an SSL cert from your own certificate authority, and posting it to a public server (hosting provider)? If that is the case, is the certificate authority that you used to create the certificates available in some way for verification? What I mean is, systems are going to try to verify the SSL cert. If your CA created it, can theses systems access your CA for verification? Also, is your CA trusted by their system?

Comment: Turns out that the error message on the form was horrible. They didn't want the ---begin--- and ---end--- parts of the cert file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X.509 certificates include a pointer to the authority that they fall under. That can include an intermediate certificate. This means you may need to install a copy of that certificate locally. Consider this [article](http://www.whichssl.com/intermediate-certificates.html).